# Algorithm name in nlminb's PORT routines?

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, nlme

I'm using `gnls` function of `nlme` package to fit a curve. When I try to know what optimizer it was using, I was directed to `nlminb` function [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nlminb.html) and it states:

> Unconstrained and box-constrained optimization using PORT routines.

I don't know what is "PORT routines". Is it a series of optimization algorithms or it's just an optimization algorithm called "PORT routines"?

Can anyone please at least tell me some names in the "routines". For example, "gradient descent", "Levenberg–Marquardt", or "trust region"?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Quasi Newton BFGS .

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you!! And do you know why is this algorithm called "port routines"? What is their relationship...? I'm just curious

Comment: It was a Fortran mathematical subroutine library designed to be *portable* over different types of computers.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Hi Mr./Mrs. I have another question of "gnls" package, I would appreciate it if you'd like to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392598/how-to-understand-gnls-r-language-generalized-least-squares-for-non-linear-m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nlminb` is an unconstrained and bounds-constrained quasi-Newton method optimizer. This code is based on a [FORTRAN PORT library by David Gay](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/misc/port.pdf) in the Bell Labs designed to be *portable* over different types of computer (from comments by Erwin Kalvelagen). See more [here](https://www.aimsciences.org/article/exportPdf?id=7e25fb2d-b50c-46dd-9be5-23deee2b4242) (Section 2).

L-BFGS-B  & BFGS, being a member of quasi-Newton family methods, are the closest analogs of `nlminb` "adaptive nonlinear least-squares algorithm".

You can see the original report at [An Adaptive Nonlinear Least-Squares Algorithm by J.E. Dennis, Jr., David M. Gay, Roy E. Welsch](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/355958.355965) (thanks to Ben Bolker's comment).

Comment: PDF of the original report: http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA079716

Comment: @Ben Bolker, thanks. I'll incorparate into the answer (however this exact link is not accessible).